How to set dataLabels position 2 Inches away from doughnut chart center?
I want to set the dataLabels away from chart center, irrespective of datalabel position
I did try calculating anglr from chart values, but unable to fix the position.
I even tried using XML parsing and none of them worked?

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
